# Understanding app background launch behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, uilocalnotification, appdelegate

In apple Doc [Understanding When Your App Gets Launched into the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

> Apps that support background execution may be relaunched by the system
>   to handle incoming events...

I am doing `region monitoring` and when I get that I am popping a `UILocalNotification`, but when I tap on `UILocalNotification` my app `didReceiveLocalNotification` is called. May be because my app is launched in background.

Second thing I did is I did not tap `UILocalNotification` and left for few minutes, means my app will terminate by iOS. I drag the notification center and then tap the `UILocalNotification` still my app enter in `didReceiveLocalNotification`.

The behavior I am expecting that app now launch in action of delayed  `UILocalNotification` tap must enter in this method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

        if (notification) 
        {
            NSLog(@"notification caused app to launch, alert body = %@", notification.alertBody);
            // do what ever action you want to do
            // you could just copy the code from "didReceiveLocalNotification" and paste it here
        }

        return YES;
    }
```

What is actually happening can please any one explain in detail?

Even after a delay when I tap `UILocalNotification` app do not enter in

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app isn't terminated after a few minutes of inactivity.
It becomes idle, and only terminated if memory is needed.
Remember that it is launched to process the region change in the background, and it sends the notification in the first place, so it's resident in the device memory in this stage.
Try to explicitly quiting it using the multitasking interface or launch several memory consuming apps (games usually do the trick) to force it to quit.
A few minutes of waiting in the background won't make it terminate.

Comment: Ok I will try that, Thank you :)